# When a checkbox is checked i want to send its value to other PHP file through jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Actually i want to send the value of checkbox  when it is checked through jquery...means when i click on checkbox it has to send automatically...i tried with following code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkBox").change(function () {
        var s = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 's=' + s;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {}
        });
    });
});
```

and html code is

```
<div class = "checkBox">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "select[]" value = <?php $friendUid?> />
</div>
```

I was unable to send to other page

Comment: When you say "it's not working", did you try any sort of debugging? Where does it fail? does the function get called, or does the code break down before that point? does the ajax call get a response, or does the code break down after that? put some work into this.

Comment: How exactly do you know that this is not working? What does script xyz.php do with the ajax request?

Comment: yeah,,,xyz.php is working..i tried it viz url.....xyz.php?s=ka

Actually  i want to get the value of the checkbox which was checked in xyz.php....

Comment: Actually i didn't use any dubugging thing as such..i am not getting where does it fails...and in xyz.php..i want to show the checked value

Comment: @Kaushik koneru How do you know it is failing at all? Your code does nothing upon a successful response back from the xyz.php script. What do you expect should be happening that your are not seeing?

Comment: i tried debbuging it was not even called (jquery function)   Actually after checking it ...i am sending its value to xyz.php and then i am adding tht value to db..

Answer (score 3):

Change your html: Put the `class = "checkBox"` onto the checkbox element

```
<div>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "select[]" value = <?php $friendUid?>  class = "checkBox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector $(".checkBox") will attach that function to any items with the class of checkBox, and since your checkbox does not have that as its class, you are actually attaching your function to the div that contains the checkbox instead, which of course will never trigger your function.

Comment: so if you move your the class assignment from the div to the input, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php $friendUid?>` should be `<?php echo $friendUid ?>`

Comment: or perhaps if shorttags are on, <?= $friendUid ?>

Comment: and actually it should also be surrounded with quote marks: value="<?= $friendUid ?>"

Comment: After making this change also it is not working.........Anyways thank u for quik reply

Answer (score 0):

with $(".checkbox") you're referencing something of class 'checkbox' (i.e., your div, not the actual checkbox).
Add the class to the `<input type='checkbox'>` instead

Comment: I tried adding class to checkbox 
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "select[]" value = "<?php echo $friendUid?> " class = "checkBox" />
this is also not workin

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code and let us know what happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('check0');
   $(document).ready(function () {
      alert('check1');
      $(".checkBox").change(function () {
         alert('check2');
         var s = $(this).val();
         var dataString = 's=' + s;
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
               alert('check3');
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" />
```

Comment: This was showing all alert's(even check 3)  but on the other page the value is not storing in database............

Comment: @Kaushik koneru then your problem is with the page that is processing the ajax request (xyz.php) not with the client side javascript.

Comment: @Kaushik koneru What do you mean by, it worked fine. Do you mean that you checked the database afterwards and the record was there, or do you mean the page then displayed what you wanted it to display?